# Do dictionaries only store references to key and values internally?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how Python dictionary optimizes its required memory internally. Following is the sample code I have written :

```
 d = dict({
  "id": {
    "mm": {
      "a": 4,
      "b": 4,
      "d": 4
    },
    "nn": {
      "a": 4,
      "b": 4,
      "e": 4
    }
  }
})
print(d["id"]["mm"])
for key, value in d["id"]["mm"].items():
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    print("key : ", key, ", value : ",value)
    print("key id : ", id(key), ", value id: ",id(value))
print("===========================================")    
print(d["id"]["nn"])    
for key, value in d["id"]["nn"].items():
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    print("key : ", key, ", value : ",value)
    print("key id : ", id(key), ", value id: ",id(value))        
print("-------------------------------------------")
```

Following is the output for the above code :

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'd': 4}
-------------------------------------------
key :  a , value :  4
key id :  31453000 , value id:  1935862320
-------------------------------------------
key :  b , value :  4
key id :  31451320 , value id:  1935862320
-------------------------------------------
key :  d , value :  4
key id :  30586728 , value id:  1935862320
===========================================
{'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'e': 4}
-------------------------------------------
key :  a , value :  4
key id :  31453000 , value id:  1935862320
-------------------------------------------
key :  b , value :  4
key id :  31451320 , value id:  1935862320
-------------------------------------------
key :  e , value :  4
key id :  30586616 , value id:  1935862320
-------------------------------------------
```

From above output, it seems that both keys and values corresponding to entries `"a": 4, "b": 4` are reused in values corresponding to `"mm"` and `"nn"`. So does Python dictionary only stores references corresponding to key and values internally for optimizing its memory footprint?

Comment: CPython caches small strings and integers since they are immutable anyway. Try with some larger integers or mutable values.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has very little to do with Python's `dict` and lot more to do with the fact that small immutable objects are cached in CPython. The comments allude to this. Here are some details:

`dict` is simply a key/value container: nothing more. The values are *always* references under the hood (`4` is a reference to an immutable integer, in particular), the question is whether or not those references are the same.

Note that the `is` keyword compares two objects to see if their id's are the same.

```
>>> a = 123456
>>> b = 123456
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a)
4343450000
>>> id(b)
4343450096
>>> c = 4
>>> d = 4
>>> c is d
True
>>> id(c)
4335519152
>>> id(d)
4335519152
```

Strings are also immutable and happen to be cached in a similar manner:

```
>>> a = "some_string"
>>> b = "some_string"
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a)
4343486192
>>> id(b)
4343486192
>>> c = "some_really_long_string_that_cpython_wont_cache_but_it_has_to_be_pretty_stinking_large_though_so_that_it_doesn't_fit_on_screen"
>>> d = "some_really_long_string_that_cpython_wont_cache_but_it_has_to_be_pretty_stinking_large_though_so_that_it_doesn't_fit_on_screen"
>>> c is d
False
>>> id(c)
4337753760
>>> id(d)
4339036736
```

It doesn't matter if you call the reference `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` (like I did in the above toy example), or if you assign it to a dictionary key/value pair.

```
>>> x = {"a": 2*3, "b": 2*3, "c": 123*100, "d": 123*100}
>>> x["a"] is x["b"]
True
>>> x["c"] is x["d"]
False
```

Same thing, we just happen to be storing the references in a data structure (`dict`).

Mutable objects are different:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a is b
False
```

because if they *were* the same, then modifying list `a` would affect list `b` (since they'd be the *same* reference). Continuing:

```
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[]
```

but if the same mutable object is pointed to by two different references, then the mutation is reflected in *both* the references (since they happen to refer to the same object):

```
>>> c = a # force c to be the same reference as a
>>> a is c
True
>>> a
[1]
>>> c
[1]
>>> a.append(3)
>>> a
[1, 3]
>>> c
[1, 3]
```

**Do dictionaries only store references to key and values internally?**

Yes. But this particular question probably doesn't mean what you think it means given your posting. See above. It should also be noted that keys are *generally* immutable.

**So does Python dictionary only stores references corresponding to key and values internally for optimizing its memory footprint?**

Yes and no. The memory footprint savings has nothing to do with `dict`, it has to do with the fact that small immutable objects are cached in CPython, and therefore every reference floating around points to the *same* object. However, using references typically does help the memory footprint (like caching or if you have many references to the same large object instead of copies of it floating around).

**P.S.** The caching mechanism is not guaranteed by the Python programming language. Other interpreters may or may not have this mechanism, so don't depend on it in your code. Best to use `==` when comparing immutable objects (assuming you want to compare their *values*), and not `is`.